# What do you make of the news that researchers had found at least 110 Tor nodes that were spying in on network traffic or were honeypots?

Tags: anonymity, deanonymization, guard-node, bittorrent

URLS for news

www.zdnet.com/article/over-100-spying-malicious-tor-nodes-discovered/

www.scmagazineuk.com/security-researchers-discover-over-100-suspicious-tor-nodes-snooping-on-traffic/article/512260/

www.linuxsecurity.com/content/view/168299/

Or search google for "tor nodes snooping"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the *researchers* were doing was creating "honeypots", the relays weren't "honeypots". The [snooping HSDir](http://donncha.is/2013/05/trawling-tor-hidden-services/) is something that's [long been acknowledged](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/hidden-services-need-some-love) as a weakness in the current rendezvous protocol. Most of these relays have likely been ejected from the consensus but as [arma stated](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/new-research-northeastern-university) the methods that the `bad-relays` hunters currently employ aren't always perfect, and it's good to have other researchers working towards the same goal through different means.

The idea works like this, onion services use HSDirs to publish their descriptors. A naughty HSDir can see these descriptors as they are published, and operators can use this to index onion services even if the onion address is never made public. Essentially, if you publish an onion service then any HSDir that you publish to can try to connect to the onion service as a normal user, since they know the address from the descriptor you gave them.

The [next-gen onion services](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/mission-montreal-building-next-generation-onion-services) will attempt to stop this kind of activity by HSDirs being possible by [encrypting the descriptors contents](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/224-rend-spec-ng.txt?id=6d968a1507ae074ab17f914522f25b68138efd42#n953) with information that a user who knows the onion address would know but the HSDir does not, through [keyblinding](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/224-rend-spec-ng.txt?id=6d968a1507ae074ab17f914522f25b68138efd42#n1719). This will defeat such attempts to discover in-use onion addresses.

It is also currently possible to encrypt the onion service descriptor with a secret that is shared out-of-band through the use of [`HiddenServiceAuth`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HiddenServiceAuthorizeClient) in `stealth` mode on the onion service and [`HidServAuth`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HidServAuth) on the client. This would mean a snooping HSDir would be unable to decrypt the descriptors contents and discover the introduction points used by the onion service or the public keys that it should use to signal to them that it would like to rendezvous with the onion service. A lesser `basic` mode is also available that would stop them successfully completing a connection but would allow them to discover the introduction points, because it does not encrypt the descriptor it just requires that the client proves knowledge of the shared secret before it will allow a user to connect.